# How to mount /var/run/docker.sock usr/bin/docker to docker container using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I want to bind my docker binaries and docker.sock to my docker jenkins container so that i will be able to use docker inside jenkins. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    restart: always
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_traefik"
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}"

  jenkins:
    #image: jenkins/jenkins
    build: .
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_jenkins"
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
    ports:
      - '50000:50000'
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${PROJECT_BASE_URL}"
```

Is there something I missed? I am not using sudo when running docker-compose start.

Comment: IME the host's `docker` binary isn't necessarily compatible with what's in the container but otherwise this looks okay at first glance.  What's not working?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make the jenkins container privileged to access a device.  By default this is turned off, probably for security.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities for more details, it even gives the example of running the docker daemon.

In your docker compose file add `privileged: true` to your jenkins service

Comment: You don't need to be privileged to access the Docker socket (assuming you have access to it).